# How to edit my bibliography (Reference) style so no "In" appear before name of journal,

Tags: bibliographies, ref

I'm new here
I would really like to know how can I edit my bibliography to appear with no "in" before the names of journals as can be seen here:

[image: what I marker in the yellow show what I want to delete]

Best regards,
Lital

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You don't like Latin?

Comment: Please tell us whether you use biblatex, bibtex, or some other program to create the bibliography.

Comment: This looks like you're using `biblatex`. If you use the `biblatex-ext` styles, there's an option to remove the `In:` `articlein=false`. These styles are the same as the standard styles but with a lot of useful hooks for easy customization.

Comment: hi , Yes! i used biblatex, thanks,  where i need to add the "articlein=false"  ? best, Lital

Comment: ok Thanks! now it works fine :)